# Android M Permissions model

Tags: android

I've been reading about the new Android permissions model, and I have a question since I can't test it right now:

*`If an app does not target the M Developer Preview, the app continues to use the old permissions model even on M Preview devices.`*

So if my app is not targeting the M Developer Preview, it wont need to check every time on granted permissions, BUT, they also say

*`Users can revoke permissions at any time from the app Settings screen.`*

So what happens when the user revokes one of my permissions while not targeting the M Developer Preview ? they say that unexpected behavior will happen, but without targeting the M version, we won't have access to new Android M methods, so in my opinion we are bound to use the new model ?

Comment: Second comment is also if application has been targated to M preview.

Comment: https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/Android-M-RuntimePermissionDemo demo to understand how the permision for contacts work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, Yes. Sooner or later we have to switch to new permission model because legacy app may behave abnormal on Android M platform in case end user revoke permission. To handle permissions in a good manner we need to switch to new permission model. To use this permission model you need to set `targetSdkVersion= MNC` (As of preview 2) After final M release need to set `targetSdkVersion=23`.

**Update:**

Android 6.0 Marshmallow is officially released. For more information check this link: http://developer.android.com/index.html

Comment: Thank you so much, another question: can we still work with eclipse ? or do we HAVE to move to android studio ?

Comment: @PankajKumar why do we need to switch? I just updated Eclipse and I can test on Android M with the emulator, can you explain please? Because i'm updating an app but I have some doubts

Comment: @VicJordan can you explain why please

Comment: No you can still work with eclipse with Android-M also. Major thing you can't use in Eclipse is cool feature of Java 1.8 because eclipse support java level till 1.7 but Android Studio does. So if you wanna use "lambda -one of cool feature of java 1.8" switch to Android Studio else continue with eclipse ( with latest SDK and latest build tool and support libraries )

Comment: @El Jazouli Since the official support of eclipse has been dropped, it is a good idea to do the switch and benefit from all the goodness Android Studio has to offer and new features that Google is adding to it but of course you don't have to its the same argument about using a text editor vs IDE. Both can get the job done but its up to you which one you want to chose. Also regarding Permissions on M, I suggest checking this library out https://goo.gl/DAAzBe

Comment: @PankajKumar Also if you want to use the newer features of Android with native Google support (e.g: TouchID) it is recommended to switch. You can still use Eclipse but if you run into issue, just remember that the Google HelpDesk will not support your mobile team.